# Add data from table to other Table SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

please i need your help 
 i have two tables 
the first one is full with all calendar data 
dim_table_start(pk_date_deb,year,month,trimester,week,date)
and i want to fill the second table with data  from dim_data_start
dim_table_end(pk_date_fin,year,month,trimester,week,date)
 i tried :

```
INSERT INTO [bd_disponibilite].[dbo].[dim_date_fin]
           ([PK_Date_fin]

           ,[Year]

           ,[Trimester]

           ,[Month]

           ,[Week]
        )
     VALUES
         (select * from dbo.dim_date_Debut)
```

but doesn't work

how can i add all data table to fill the second table thank you

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `VALUES` portion when inserting records using `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO [bd_disponibilite].[dbo].[dim_date_fin]
           ([PK_Date_fin]
           ,[Year]
           ,[Trimester]
           ,[Month]
           ,[Week]
           )
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.dim_date_Debut
```

Comment: Thank yo very much for help

Comment: @Goat CO is correct. I'd just like to add some useful info. If you are only doing this insert once it's fine, but if you plan to re-use it I would be specific about the columns you are selecting instead of using `Select *`. It future proofs your code against somebody adding a column to the schema of `dim_date_Debut`, which would break your insert. I see this kind of bug a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If the destination doesn't exist yet, you can also use 
SELECT *
INTO dbo.dim_date_fin
from dbo.dim_date_Debut

This is speedier to code because it copies the schema as well.

If the table exists or needs different properties, Goat's answer is better.